# Jack probs with heaphones/earbuds

Tags: laptop, audio, microphone, acer-aspire

So I already asked this question, but I couldn't respond to the answers. I can't hear out of the left ear of any headphones/earbuds because I have to push the jack towards the Earth to hear out of it. It seems you guys think the jack is the problem when I'm pretty sure it's the computer (my Acer laptop). I also forgot to mention the headphones (PX22 Turtle Beaches) work with both ears, but I have to plug in the usb extension cord in order for that to work (it's also the same cord that enables the mic on my headphones), plus I lost the cord. Thanks 4 hewps.

Comment: Nico, This post will probably get deleted as a duplicate.  The thing to do is edit your original question to clarify anything related to the answers or to provide additional information.  Add the information in this post and explain anything you think is diagnostic.

Comment: If you don't have access to your old account you need to go here: http://superuser.com/contact

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing is a mechanical problem.  The tip of the plug is the left channel.  The very end is bulb-shaped and the contact snaps behind that.  It's likely one of two things.

The contacts inside the jack can get bent or fatigue and lose their springiness.  It is not easy to do much about either of those if that's the problem except replace the jack, and that is not a trivial job.

The other thing is that not all plugs are manufactured exactly alike.  Some are slightly shorter, have a smaller bulb at the tip or the bulb is shaped a little differently, or the molded handle may prevent the plug from going all the way in.  For that matter, the jack may be out of tolerance.  Any of these things can prevent the tip contact from snapping into place and making a good connection.  Through trial and error, you may find either a headphone extension cord, adapter, or replacement plug that fits the jack better.

If you find such a replacement plug, use it to make an adapter or extension, and plug the headphones into that.  Don't try to replace the plug on the headphones.  The cord often has a type of wire that is very hard to work with to make new connections.